# Qui n'aurait jamais songé

Tags: conditionnel, conditionnel-passé

Bonjour,

*Roses de sang Roses d'Ouessant* de Janine Boissard :

> Eric n'avait jamais aimé Morgane. Son attitude martiale, son franc
> parler, ses jugements à l'emporte-pièce, la lui faisait classer parmi
> les "féministes enragées". Pauvre Morgane qui n'**aurait** jamais **songé** à
> les rejoindre et leur reprochait même une trop grande brutalité envers
> le sexe faible : les hommes, bien entendu.

Est-ce que l'auteure emploie le conditionnel passé "n'**aurait** jamais **songé**" pour exprimer une hypothèse ?

Comment: Voilà une phrase très bizarre : un bon niveau de brutalité envers le sexe faible parait acceptable, il faut tout simplement ne pas exagérer !

Comment: @LPH Ce n'est pas moi qui ai écrit cette phrase, je voulais simplement savoir pourquoi l'on emploie le conditionnel passé ici. En plus, ce sont des pensées du narrateur... qui pourrait se tromper, être injuste, grossier, etc.

Comment: @LPH L'humour du texte semble t'avoir échappé. Ni l'auteur, ni les protagonistes ne soutiennent une quelconque brutalité ici, et encore moins contre les femmes.

Comment: ne pas songer=ne pas imaginer

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agit d'une hypothèse dont la condition est sous entendue, par exemple :

> *Pauvre Morgane qui n'aurait jamais songé à rejoindre les "féministes enragées" **si on le lui avait proposé**.*

ou

> *Pauvre Morgane qui n'aurait jamais songé à rejoindre les "féministes enragées" **si l'occasion s'était présentée.***

Référence :

> Le bon usage, 14<sup>e</sup> édition
>
> [...] Le conditionnel passé exprime dans le passé les mêmes valeurs
> que le conditionnel présent exprime dans le présent ou le futur.
> [...] Soit qu'il marque un fait imaginaire (et donc irréel) ou conjectural concernant le passé (ordinairement, un fait futur par rapport à un moment du passé).
>
> - Le fait conjectural dépend d'une condition : *Si tu avais mené la moindre enquête à Paris, tu en AURAIS APPRIS de belles* (MAURIAC, Ce qui était perdu, IV). — *La condition peut être exprimée par des tournures diverses : Un siècle plus tôt, on /'AURAIT MIS à la Bastille*. — N'étaient ses sentiments religieux, il se SERAIT JETÉ dans la Seine (BALZAC, Birotteau, p. 39). — **Parfois la condition n'est pas exprimée** : *Nos cœurs d'enfants étaient trop tendres
>   [...]. Ils se SERAIENT BRISÉS* (M. PRÉVOST, M, le Jaufre, II, 5).

<sub>C'est moi qui ai graissé.</sub>

Comment: Merci, je n'étais pas sûre à cause de la narration au passé.

Comment: Pas d'hypothèse sous-entendue, qu'on le lui ait proposé ou pas elle n-y aurait jamais songé parce qu'elle était d'une telle nature que cela ne pouvait pas lui venir à l'esprit.

Comment: @LPH L'hypothèse n'est pas figée. J'ai donné un exemple mais d'autres peuvent aussi aider à comprendre la valeur du conditionnel passé, Par exemple: *Elle n'y aurait jamais songé même si l'occasion s'était présentée.*

Answer (score 1):

Non, ce conditionnel ne sert pas à émettre une hypothèse. Dans ce contexte il peut être utilisé pour marquer une opposition entre deux idées, l'une, qui semble irréalisable, au conditionnel (forme négative), et l'autre, réelle ou qui est considérée comme réalisable, à un autre temps ; c'est assez souvent le cas. Il n'est pas clair qu'il existerait une telle opposition dans la phrase de Boissart, mais ce conditionnel peut aussi simplement exprimer une action qui ne semble pas réalisable.

*Quelques exemples*

*cas d'opposition*

- Jean, qui n'aurait jamais cru qu'il passerait son examen, apprenait par le journal le matin même qu'il était reçu.
- L'idée d'utiliser toutes les ressources des occupants de la maison venait d'Hélène, elle qui n'aurait pourtant jamais voulu toucher aux économies.
- Lui qui  n'aurait jamais été partisan du moindre effort, parlait maintenant de mettre les bouchées doubles.

*Cas dans lesquels l'idée d'opposition n'existe pas*

- C'était un homme malade, qui n'aurait pas fait de mal à une mouche, et il n'avait de rancune pour personne.
- C'était une âme simple et douce qu'on n'aurait pas soupçonnée de méchanceté.

**Note** Désolé, je ne trouve pas de références.